# Generic many2many relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-contenttypes

So, I have the 4 entities represented below which are strong and independent entities on my application, now the problem is that each Article or Picture could be "tagged" with a Presenter or an Event, being as they are the 4 of them independent entities that could become more complex It doesn't look right to add Event and Presenter field to both Article and Picture or the contrary, specially because they could be tagged with none.
In the long run as well other entities might need to be tagged and other taggable entities might appear.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    #Fields
class Picture(models.Model):
    #Fields
class Presenter(models.Model):
    # Fields
class Event(models.Model):
    # Fields
```

The closer I am getting is to some kind of double-headed Generic contenttype based intermediate model like this(haven't tested yet as it is a bit more complex than that), but I am looking for ideas:

```
class GenericTag(models.Model):
    # Event,Presenter instance..
    tagcontent_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    tagobject_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tagcontent_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('tagcontent_type', 'tagobject_id')
    # Picture,Article instance
    objcontent_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    objobject_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    objcontent_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('objcontent_type', 'objobject_id')
```

And with that just do queries based on the information I have, I think there have to be more elegant ways to do this without stuffing all tagmodels as fields into taggablemodels.

Comment: Is it many-to-many relation, or one-to-many? From your question it looks like Article or Picture could have only one Presenter and one Event, but title says "many2many".

Comment: One Picture can have several Presenters and one Presenter could be in several Pictures, same for Articles and Events.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach without generic foreign keys would be to use model inheritance:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    pass
class Taggable(models.Model):
    pass

class Article(Taggable):
    # Fields
class Picture(Taggable):
    # Fields
class Presenter(Tag):
    # Fields
class Event(Tag):
    # Fields

class TagInstance(models.Model):
    tagged = models.ForeignKey(Taggable)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
```

This introduces additional tables for the two base classes and shared primary-key spaces for their respective instances, so they can be referenced with ordinary foreign keys. This might be reasonable depending on what further you want to do with your tags.

Comment: The part I don't like about this solution is that those 4 entities need to be inheriting from (Tag|Taggable) for this to work, and as they are entities that belong to their own app their don't fit my model